# How to get started with github projects?

Tags: github

I can do programming well.But when I go see some project on github I don't understand how I can make contribution or modify the project.As there are so many files in the project.so please help me find a proper path to get started.

Comment: This question is not fit for StackOverflow because what you're asking has nothing to do with programming. Here are some links to help you: https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/ , https://akrabat.com/the-beginners-guide-to-contributing-to-a-github-project/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the prerequisite programming knowledge (or at least enough to understand what you're reading and learn as you go) I would suggest just going straight to the issue tracker on whatever github project you're looking at.

A lot of open source issue trackers have tags some of which are very helpfully labeled  easy, hard, etc. (like MatPlotLib), so I would start by checking out some of the easy ones that have been completed (i.e. code has been integrated) and looking at how it was done in order to get familiar with the project's codebase.

Once you get a little comfy with their code base start tackling some of the open issues there, devs are usually pretty willing to point you in the right direction if you ask for help!

Comment: Can you tell me some projects in c and java that I can start working on?